# JQuery Virtual Keyboard and Datatables.js search filter box not updating on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, keyboard

I have datatables.js application that works allongside a jquery virtual keyboard. When using the virtual keyboard to enter information into the generated search box, the filtered content does not work. Meaning that if I have a column `names` and search a name(e.g Airi) with the virtual keyboard, the information inside the datatables does not get updated. If I remove it it works.

The code that I am using for the datatable is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  $('#example').DataTable();
  // example for the virtual keyboard on datatable search
  // this shows the keyboard but the content is not filtered
  function virtualKSearch() {    
        $('input[type="search"]').keyboard({
                layout: 'qwerty',
                draggable: true,
                position: {
                  of : $(window),
                  my : 'center bottom',
                  at : 'center bottom',
                  at2: 'center bottom'  
                },
                change: function(e, keyboard, el) {
                  keyboard.$el.val(keyboard.$preview.val())
                  keyboard.$el.trigger('propertychange')        
                },
                reposition: true
         }).addTyping();
      }
  // example for the bootstrap select keyboard, this works
  $('input[role="textbox"]').keyboard(
    {
      layout: 'qwerty',
      position: {
          of: $(window), 
          my: 'center bottom',
          at: 'center bottom',
          at2: 'center bottom'
      },
      change: function(e, keyboard, el) {
        keyboard.$el.val(keyboard.$preview.val())
        keyboard.$el.trigger('propertychange')        
      }
    })
    .addTyping();

  // datatable example
  virtualKSearch();

});
```

At first I thought that it had to do with the `propertyChange` but after some modification it seems to not be the case. Although I believe that the issue might be inside of the `change` property inside the keyboard setting.

The content can be replicated inside this pen:

https://codepen.io/AlecX4/pen/YrKYPv

Any tips or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: asking for a friend

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I managed to fix it. For anyone that gets stuck on this...the solution was quite simple:

Change

```
              keyboard.$el.trigger('propertychange')
```

to

```
              keyboard.$el.trigger('input')
```